How to install Magento 2 on Macbook Air M1, running Ventura?
I tried manually installing magento 2 using the command:
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/m2/ \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=m2 \
--db-user=root \
--db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Vladimir \
--admin-lastname=Despotovic \
--admin-email=your_email@example.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/New_York \
--use-rewrites=1

I also tried using the warden installation, in details and I tried several bugfixes myself with it - once it didn't run correctly (the M2 did not successfully finish the installation):
https://github.com/wardenenv/

I also tried this method:
https://magetu.com/how-to-install-magento-2-4-5-with-warden/?i=1

I Also tried the oneliner method:
https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

getting this error (among many other before it, that I kind of circumvented):
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m2/src/app/design': mkdir /host_mnt/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m2/src: no such file or directory

and if I create that directory manually, just to cheat the Docker, then I get this:
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m2/src/composer.lock': mkdir /host_mnt/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m2/src: no such file or directory

Or sometimes this error:
chmod: cannot access 'bin/magento': No such file or directory

and nothing worked. Do you know what is a strightforward way to install, or, just a method that worked for you, on Mac OS Ventura? I am tired of trying....Thanks in advance for any help on this.

I've been using Warden on my Mac M2 Pro Max for over a year without any issues. Could you let me know what problem you're experiencing with Warden?

@KhoaTruongDinh too many issues with Docker....with opensearch, and everything else regarding it, so I eventually gave up on that. Meanwhile, I managed to install Magento 2 using CLI. Not Warden, but CLI, so, using terminal.

Try MAMP. I use it for years for Magento since Magento 1.

I am using MAMP, yes. And, I am asking about Magento 2, not Magento 1.

Yes I use Mag 2 too. Just mentioned that I use MAMP since M1.
Try to use direct install without Docker. When run CLI command use command with the full path to MAMP php version like /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade or create alias for it. Otherwise it will load Mac php currently active in your system. Make sure folder with Mag has proper permission.

As a long-time Magento 2 developer with years of experience using both Mark Shust’s docker-magento and Warden on Macbook M2, I can help you resolve the issues you're encountering. Here are two specific errors and their solutions:

Error: "Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/path/to/a/file/in/your/installation/folder: no such file or directory"
This error is related to a known issue with Docker Desktop (GitHub Issue #487). It typically occurs when Docker is unable to mount a file or directory from your host machine. The solution is to adjust your Docker preferences to resolve the file-sharing issue.

Fix:
To resolve this, go to Docker Desktop > Preferences > General and disable the "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" option. This setting can interfere with Docker’s ability to correctly share files between your host and containers. Disabling it should resolve the error.
By the way, as Mark Shust mentioned, we switched to using OrbStack instead of Docker Desktop over a year ago. Since then, we've encountered far fewer issues, it’s faster, and it consumes 90% less battery and resources. I’d highly recommend it over Docker Desktop! https://orbstack.dev/

Error: "chmod: cannot access 'bin/magento': No such file or directory"
This error occurs during the setup process when the bin/magento file, which is part of the Magento 2 base package, isn't being generated or synced properly. It’s usually a result of an incomplete or broken installation.

Fix: To resolve this, run the following commands inside the Docker container to manually reinstall the Magento 2 base package:
rm -rf vendor/magento/magento2-base && composer install

This will remove the existing base package and reinstall it, ensuring the bin/magento file is correctly generated.

Additional Notes:

MAMP Conflicts:
It appears that you might be running MAMP, which can cause conflicts with Docker, especially when trying to set up Magento. I recommend stopping MAMP during the setup process to avoid any issues. Additionally, it's best to install your Magento project outside of the MAMP folder to prevent further conflicts.


For your information, I’m the author of the Magento 2 installation guides on Magetu.com. My blog posts focus solely on providing a guide for installing and setting up Magento 2 projects with Warden. This is because Mark Shust's docker-magento already provides detailed instructions, along with a free course to help you set up the project, familiarize yourself with Docker, and apply customizations to the Docker setup. Since this is already well-covered, I didn't include a guide for that Docker configuration. I’ll be sure to mention this in my post and update it accordingly.

Benefits of Using Docker for Magento 2
Using Docker for your Magento 2 development environment offers several key advantages, particularly when it comes to managing critical services. Here’s why Docker is a valuable tool for Magento developers:
Simplified Service Management: Docker automates the deployment and management of essential services like MariaDB/MySQL, Elasticsearch/OpenSearch, Redis, and Varnish, ensuring each service runs in an isolated container. This saves you from the manual setup and configuration of each service.
Consistent Environments Across Systems: Docker provides a consistent environment for all developers on the team, eliminating the common problem of "it works on my machine." This consistency is particularly important in collaborative environments and for smoother testing and production deployments.
Faster Setup & Scalability: With Docker, you can quickly spin up the necessary services with minimal effort. Additionally, scaling services (such as adding more database containers or search engines) is straightforward, ensuring your system can grow with your project.
Isolated Dependencies: Docker allows each service to run independently, avoiding conflicts between different software versions or dependencies. This is especially useful when running multiple services, such as different versions of MySQL or Elasticsearch, alongside your Magento instance.
Easier Maintenance and Updates: Docker simplifies maintaining and updating your development environment. If you need to update or upgrade a service, you can do so in isolation without affecting other services. Plus, Docker makes it easy to roll back to a previous version if an update causes issues.
Reproducible Development Environments: Docker makes it possible to recreate your entire development environment on any machine, ensuring that the setup is always the same for everyone involved. This reproducibility prevents environment-specific bugs and makes it easy to set up new developer environments quickly.
Overall, Docker greatly simplifies Magento 2 development by eliminating much of the manual configuration of services and dependencies, allowing you to focus on developing and maintaining your application.

lol....orb stack look even worse. Nothing of this worked for me. Eventually, I managed to install magento 2 using just the CLI.

The point of such a tool is actually, not for the core developers, of it, to be able to use it, but also for a end user, such as me, being a PHP and magento developer, but not a core developer.You need to make the tool more simple to use, so it is ACTUALLY usable.So that I do not need to put a week's effort just so I'm able to use your tool, which I didn't want to do in the first place. My only goal is to install Magento and install some modules.Not to work on developing someone else's tool which , doesn't even work. Sorry to be brutally honest here, just thought I'd give you a lamen's opinion

Ok i will try undoing the gRPC and will let you know here, if it worked. As I said, in the meanwhile however, I managed to install Magento 2 using just the CLI, no docker.

Sorry to hear that you had a bad experience when trying to install Magento locally, especially if you're not familiar with Docker and Magento installation. I'm sure that with the solutions I've provided, you'll be able to set up Magento 2 on your machine. We'll see.
